# Load and unload for cmake like in VS MSBuild

Tags: cmake

Maybe someone knows if there is such an opportunity to recreate this functionality in cmake?
That is, some subproject was in the project but would not be built by default.
Thx.

Comment: set an `option(USE_SUBPRJ1 "My sub prj1" ON)` then enclose with an if statement, according to that `add_subdirectory(mysubprj1)`. Run CMake again.